# Is this expression uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Given two numbers $x\in (0,1)$ and $y\in (0,1)$, think of the expression
$\min_{n\ge 1} \frac{1-x}{(1-xy)x^{n-1}(1-y^n)}$.

Does the supremum of this expression, namely, 
$\sup_{x,y\in (0,1)}\min_{n\ge 1} \frac{1-x}{(1-xy)x^{n-1}(1-y^n)}$
be finite or infinite?

I greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: I would like to derive this to say something about the trading strategy in my finance research :)

Comment: You can use the rule of l'hospital to see how the term behaves on the boundary. Look at the limits $x\rightarrow 0, \ x\rightarrow 1,\ y\rightarrow 0$ or  $y\rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 1$ we have $2^{n-1}\ge n$. We have $y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}+\cdots+1\le n$ for $y\in(0,1)$.  We thus have

$${2^{n-1}\over y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}+\cdots+1}\ge 1$$

and thus

$${2^{n-1}\over (1-y)(y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}+\cdots+1)} ={2^{n-1}\over 1-y^n}\ge {1\over 1-y}$$

Now consider the expression in the original problem, whose supremum we are trying to determine.  Set $x={1\over2}$.  We get

$$\sup_{y\in (0,1)}\min_{n\ge 1} \frac{2^{n-1}}{2(1-y/2)(1-y^n)}\ge \sup_{y\in (0,1)} {1\over 2(1-y/2)(1-y)}=+\infty$$

Fingers crossed I haven't made a mistake.